# select count(*) is Metadata operation

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I read in the [document](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-query-profile.html#metadata-operators) that `select count(*)` is a Metadata operation in snowflake. SO no computation is warehouse used. But without any warehouse assigned the query `select count(*)` cannot be run. And once warehouse start it will start using credits. Can any one please explain this.

Answer (score 2):

The count(*) does not require a running warehouse. You can see this behavior using this script:

```
-- Shut down a warehouse and do not allow auto-resume to test this
alter warehouse test suspend;
alter warehouse test set auto_resume = false;
use warehouse test;

-- This fails because it needs a running warehouse
select * from "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCH_SF1"."ORDERS" limit 1;

-- This works because it's a metadata query
select count(*) from "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCH_SF1"."ORDERS";

-- Simple aritemetic math on metadata queries is okay
select count(*) + 1 from "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCH_SF1"."ORDERS";

-- Running functions requires a warehouse
select sqrt(count(*)) from "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCH_SF1"."ORDERS";

--Remember to alter your warehouse back to auto-resume:
alter warehouse test set auto_resume = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

The query can be run without any warehouse assigned - easy enough to test using the WebUI